# Lock hangs (deadlock?) with two transactions

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, locking

SQL Server: lock hangs (deadlock?)

```
get JDBC connection
start transaction T1
select 1 from Foo WITH (UPDLOCK) where id=1;

try {
    get another JDBC connection
    start transaction T2
    SET LOCK_TIMEOUT 0
    select 1 from Foo WITH (UPDLOCK) where id=1;  <------------ hang, wait forever
    commit transaction T2
} catch (Exception e) {
   rollback T2
}
```

All the statements above are run in one Java thread.
The 2nd lock should return immediately because LOCK_TIMEOUT is set to 0, but it waits forever.

For oracle, using

```
select ... for update
```

The code works as expected.

Tried SSMS:

Query 1: connection 1

```
use my_db;
create table Foo (id int, name nvarchar(30));
insert into Foo (id, name) values (1, 'A'), (2,'B');

begin transaction
select 1 from Foo with (UPDLOCK) where id=1;
```

Query 2: connection 2

```
use my_db;
begin transaction
set LOCK_TIMEOUT 60000;
select 1 from Foo with (UPDLOCK) where id=1;
commit transaction;
```

Run query1, then run query2. Query2 run to complete without any waiting time
and no lock timeout error.

Comment: It won't be a deadlock if it hangs forever... deadlocks are detected quite quickly and one process killed. The first process can't be releasing its locks, often that means the transaction isn't committed. You'd need to show us what happens in the first connection.

Comment: Yeah. There is no way this deadlocks - it CAN be an index missing resulting in table scans, tons of locks, slow processing. It is NOT a deadlock.

Comment: The table Foo has only 3 rows. That is all for transaction 1 and 2.

Comment: for update. this is mini-code for illustrating the issue. The 2nd lock should throw exception (lock error) immediately without waiting.

Comment: `start transaction` isn't valid T-SQL?

Comment: It is JDBC, not actual T-SQL.  connection.setAutoCommit(false);

Comment: Maybe `SET LOCK_TIMEOUT 0` doesn't work from JDBC? The scenario you describe works as expected from SSMS.

Comment: do you use two connections in SSMS?

Comment: JDBC "SET LOCK_TIMEOUT 0" without error.

Comment: for microsoft jdbc you could set the connection property lockTimeout=0 .. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/setting-the-connection-properties